# "Ok" command box in userform

Tags: excel, vba

basically I have a userform which I would like to use to enter 2 data into another macro which I already have. The userform is as below:

[image]

Basically, I would like the OK button to be clicked and the data in the two boxes will be entered into another macro that I have. It would also be great if the OK button can help in a sense that it will prompt a warning if one of the boxes is not filled up.

So far, I do not have much of a code for this..

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

TextBox1.SetFocus

Sub Enterval()


End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ID As String

    ID = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim ID2 As String

    ID2 = UserForm3.TextBox2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub OKay_Click()

Enterval

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any tips and help. Thanks!

My other macro

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Name As String
Dim Problem As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ItsAMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Name = Source.Range("A3")
Problem = Source.Range("I13")

Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(4 + i, 6)) ' This will loop down through non empty cells from row 5 of column 2
    If Target.Cells(4 + i, 6) = Name Then
        ItsAMatch = True
        Target.Cells(4 + i, 7) = Problem ' This will overwrite your "Problem" value if the name was already in the column
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

' This will write new records if the name hasn't been already found
If ItsAMatch = False Then
    Target.Cells(3, 6).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Name
    Target.Cells(4, 6).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = Problem
End If

Set Source = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thats the macro i have. As u said, i change the

```
othermacro
```

to `CommandButton1_Click()`

but it doesn't work

Comment: How should i write for the Enterval which is the sub for the OK function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an Enterval function.  Instead, assume the user can read and follow instructions, then test whether that indeed is the case.  Note that in your code `ID` and `ID2` will never be used because they exist only within the scope of the subroutines in which they are declared and receive values.

To get started:

```
    Sub Okay_Click()
        Dim sID1 As String, sID2 As String
        sID1 = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value
        sID2 = UserForm3.TextBox2.Value

        If Len(sID1 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Box A is empty"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Len(sID2 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Box B is empty"
            Exit Sub
        End If

'Now do something with sID1, sID2
        otherMacro(sID1, sID2)

    End Sub
```

For your other macro, declare it like this:

```
Sub otherMacro(ID1, ID2)
...
End Sub
```

Also, the `SetFocus` method should occur in the form open event.

Comment: thanks.looking at this. once i entered the values in and click ok can the values go to another macro that this userform is working with?

Comment: I tried putting values in to the box, no matter what, it says Box A is empty

Comment: I think i got it sorted. Just a last qn, how do i get it to interact with the other macro that i have?

Comment: Since your other macro belonged in your post and not in mine, I've edited my answer to show the usage of the entered variables.  The variables are passed as arguments for `otherMacro`.

Comment: I tried the otherMacro but it says that a syntax error.

Comment: Again, please post (as an edit to your original question) the macro so we can see the code that doesn't work.  Also, if possible, post the error message you get.

Comment: sorry geoB for the late reply! i edited the macro in

Comment: I'm guessing you did not write the "otherMacro()", as its sophistication is not reflected in your original code. Do the two routines `Okay_Click()` and ` CommandButton1_Click()` appear in the same workbook?  Is there some reason why they cannot be combined into action on the click of a single button?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting geoB except for one thing: when you `.Show` your UserForm from a main Sub, you can also `.Hide` it at the end and the macro that called it will continue its procedures.

```
    Sub Okay_Click()
    Dim sID1 As String, sID2 As String

    ' A little variation
    If Me.TextBox1 = "" Or Me.TextBox2 = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Please fill all the input fields"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Me.Hide

    End Sub
```

To address your TextBox, you can write in your main Sub `UserForm3.TextBox1` for example